# Unable to set foreign key using gorm Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm building a Golang backend using [jinzhu/gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) and I'm having some troubles trying to set up a relation between two tables e.g. *Items* and *Manufacturers* using a foreign key.

I'm following the steps at [jinzhu.me/gorm/models](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/models.html) but I'm honestly finding myself puzzled coming from a more straightforward approach of manually writing tables etc, for instance, using [go pq](https://github.com/lib/pq).

**item.go**:

```
package model

import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

type Item struct {
    gorm.Model
    Item         string       `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Manufacturer Manufacturer `gorm:"ForeignKey:Name"`
}
```

**manufacturer.go**:

```
package model

import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

type Manufacturer struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `gorm:"primary_key"`
}
```

I get no errors nor warnings. Inspecting my tables I noticed no correlation was created. Item does not have Manufacturer field.

What I tried so far:

- Not explicitly writing `gorm:"ForeignKey:Name"` since `Manufacturer` field is already a `Manufacturer`
- Writing `gorm:"ForeignKey:Name;AssociationForeignKey:Name"`
- Manually associating them with `db.Model(&model.Item{}).Related(&model.Manufacturer{})`
- Manually associating them with `db.Model(&model.Item{}).Related(&model.Manufacturer{}, "Manufacturer")`
- Manually associating them with `db.Model("items").Related("manufacturers")`. They get created with this name on Postgresql even though their model's name is singular.

**EDIT**:

Trying something like

```
type Item struct {
    Item             string       `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Manufacturer     Manufacturer
    ManufacturerID   int
}

type Manufacturer struct {
    ID uint
    Name string
}
```

Leads to the same result. No foreign key is created and I'm able to insert new items with a non-existent `Manufacturer`.

**What Am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 3):

You have to do something like:

```
type Item struct {
    gorm.Model
    Item         string       `gorm:"primary_key"`
    ManufacturerName string   `sql:"type:varchar REFERENCES manufacturers(name)"`
    Manufacturer Manufacturer `gorm:"ForeignKey:ManufacturerName;AssociationForeignKey:Name`
}
```

To tell it to a) Use ManufacturerName as the foreign key, and B) use Name on the other table.

Or you can just do:

```
type Item struct {
    gorm.Model
    Item         string       `gorm:"primary_key"`
    ManufacturerID uint       `sql:"type:uint REFERENCES manufacturers(id)"`
    Manufacturer Manufacturer `gorm:"ForeignKey:Man;AssociationForeignKey:Name"`
}
```

Comment: It does not work. `ManufacturerName` gets create but it's not a foreign key. If you insert a new item with `ManufacturerName = 'test'` and `Manufacturer` does not have any entry for `test` it does not throw any error. Also, using PGAdmin, it seems like not creating any foreign key constraint at all. Anyways you should edit your answer fixing *foriegn* to *foreign*.

Comment: It looks like gorm has some problems with actually creating the foreign key (per https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/23), but it seems like you can use the `sql` tags to create the actual key - you just have to be careful about the order that you automigrate so that the table it references already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Try this please

```
    type Item struct {
        Item             string       `gorm:"primary_key"`
        Manufacturer     Manufacturer `gorm:"foreignKey:ManufacturerID;references:id"`
        ManufacturerID   int
    }
    
    type Manufacturer struct {
        ID uint
        Name string
    }

    DB.AutoMigrate(&Item{},&Manufacturer{})

    item := Item{
        Item:         "item",
        Manufacturer: Manufacturer{
            Name:     "name"
        },
    }
    
    DB.Create(&item)
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any of the solutions I found working for this while following gorm's documentation / googling / stack overflow.  Here's what worked for me:

I have a Call object & TranscriptItem object.

A call can have many transcript items but a transcript item can only have one call.

Call object

```
type Call struct {
    gorm.Model
    DialInNumber      string
}
```

Transcript object

```
type TranscriptItem struct {
    gorm.Model
    Transcript string
    CallID     uint
}
```

I have my auto migration and a manual AddForeignKey migration

```
    db.AutoMigrate(&Call{}, &TranscriptItem{})
    db.Model(&TranscriptItem{}).AddForeignKey("call_id", "calls(id)", "RESTRICT", "RESTRICT")
```

I would've preferred to use the mechanics outlined in gorm's documentation, but at the end of the day I just needed something that worked.

Comment: Would you be able help me with a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836572/why-does-foreign-key-not-get-generated-with-gorm Foreign key is not being created with GORM