# Why does foreign key not get generated with GORM?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to create a foreign key on the `Password` table which must point to the `id` column inside the `User` table. But as I try the following, it does not work. The `foreign key` is not generated. It simply adds the column name `user_id` inside the `password` table.

```
package schema

import (
"github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
_ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string `gorm:"not null"`
    LastName string `gorm:"not null"`
    Email string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index"`
    IsActive bool `gorm:"not null"`
    IsVerified bool `gorm:"not null"`
}

type Password struct {
    gorm.Model
    Password string `gorm:"not null"`
    UserId int `gorm:"not null"`
    User User `gorm:"foreignkey:UserId;association_foreignkey:id"`
}


func SyncDB(db *gorm.DB) {

    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Password{})
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I make a foreign key inside `Password` table pointing to `User` table?

Comment: In mysql you would have to have an id in user (and it would need to be indexed) for the FK to be valid. I have no knowledge of gorm - does it do that for you?

Comment: You misplaced the closing double quote in the gorm tag of the User field. Run `go vet` to find such errors.

Comment: @Peter Have updated my question. Even after fixing double quotes it does not work

Comment: @Peter On seeing the schema using `show create table password` I cannot find any foreign key constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
db.Model(&Password{}).AddForeignKey("user_id", "users(id)", "RESTRICT", "RESTRICT")
```

I put mine after my auto migrate statement like so

```
db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Password{})
db.Model(&Password{}).AddForeignKey("user_id", "users(id)", "RESTRICT", "RESTRICT")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
type Password struct {
   gorm.Model
   Password string `gorm:"not null"`
   UserId int `gorm:"not null"`
   User User `gorm:"foreignkey:UserId;references:id"`
}
```

Comment: This will add the user columns to the password table also.